# Sirikit StartAudioCall Fail

Tags: ios, voip, ios10, sirikit

Test Background:
Xcode: Xcode8 beta6
iPhone: iOS10 beta6
Language: object-c

I have used startAudioCall sirikit in my App to test my app call. However, the sirikit will fail in some situation:
If the person's name is a first name in local contact, when I say "Call firstname myApp", siri can start myApp get this contact name successfully
But if the person's name is both first name and last name, when I say "Call firstname(or both first name and last name) myApp" , siri will call this person using phone call(not myApp)

For exsample:
if John in my phone contact, and I say "call John myApp", this will start myApp and get this contact name successfully.
But if John Smith in my phone contact, and I say "call John(or John Smith) myApp" , siri will use phone call to call this person(not myApp)

```
- (void)resolveContactsForStartAudioCall:(INStartAudioCallIntent *)intent
                      withCompletion:(void (^)(NSArray<INPersonResolutionResult *> *resolutionResults))completion{
NSLog(@"maytest resolveContactsForStartAudioCall");


NSArray<INPerson *> *recipients = intent.contacts;

NSMutableArray<INPersonResolutionResult *> *resolutionResults = [NSMutableArray array];



if (recipients.count == 0) {

    completion(@[[INPersonResolutionResult needsValue]]);
    return;
}else if(recipients.count==1){
    [resolutionResults addObject:[INPersonResolutionResult successWithResolvedPerson:recipients.firstObject]];
}else if(recipients.count>1){
     [resolutionResults addObject:[INPersonResolutionResult disambiguationWithPeopleToDisambiguate:recipients]];
}else{
    [resolutionResults addObject:[INPersonResolutionResult unsupported]];

}
completion(resolutionResults); 
}

- (void)confirmStartAudioCall:(INStartAudioCallIntent *)intent
               completion:(void (^)(INStartAudioCallIntentResponse *response))completion{

NSUserActivity *userActivity = [[NSUserActivity alloc] initWithActivityType:NSStringFromClass([INStartAudioCallIntent class])];
INStartAudioCallIntentResponse *response = [[INStartAudioCallIntentResponse alloc] initWithCode:INStartAudioCallIntentResponseCodeReady userActivity:userActivity];
completion(response);
}

- (void)handleStartAudioCall:(INStartAudioCallIntent *)intent
              completion:(void (^)(INStartAudioCallIntentResponse *response))completion{
NSUserActivity *userActivity = [[NSUserActivity alloc] initWithActivityType:NSStringFromClass([INStartAudioCallIntent class])];

INStartAudioCallIntentResponse *response = [[INStartAudioCallIntentResponse alloc] initWithCode:INStartAudioCallIntentResponseCodeContinueInApp userActivity:userActivity];
completion(response);
}
```

And Here is my code about audiocall. 
Anyone can help ? Thx a lot

Comment: So when you say, "call John myApp" and siri uses phone instead of your app, is your resolveContactsForStartAudioCall method called?

Comment: No, it will not comes to resolveContactsForStartAudioCall this function, so, I have no idea how to control this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue, after I changed the App name from "ST Wifi Calling" to "testApp".

Now, no matter I say "Use testApp to call John" or "Use testApp to call John Smith", it's going well on sirikit

I think it's too hard for Siri to recognize a long App name with space

Comment: This guy reported the same issue and was told to file a radar. My app "Kitchen Wall" doesn't work but if I change the display name to "KitchenWall" it works perfectly. https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/171140#171140