# Sirikit 'send a messages using My App' working just few times

Tags: message, siri, sirikit

I'm developing an app who allows Siri to send messages.
Few days ago everything was working fine and everytime I was saying 'Send a message using "MyApp name"' it was showing the SiriUI and it was handling the command correctly.

But since a couple of days I get a different behaviour!
Sometimes Siri opens my app, sometimes it says: "Here's what I found on the web for 'Send a message using 'myapp name':", sometimes "I don't understand 'Send a message using 'myapp' and sometimes I get the right behaviour that I used to get all the time.

Of course my app is enabled in Settings>Siri>App support

This is a really strange behaviour. I can't be more helpful, I'm sorry.
I can just say that this problem verifies with two different phone that I'm using to debug and I have tried to download a sample project online (on github) and I have the same problem.
I'm using always my provioning profile, in particular 'Xcode Automatically manage signing' is enabled

Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same issue. Try to update ```AppIntentVocabulary.plist```

Comment: It used to happen with me sometimes, I uninstalled and then re-installed the app again and it worked.

Comment: AppIntentVocabulary.plist wasn't set up and I tried to uninstall and install it again, and even create a new test project!
Then suddenly started working again. Very strange behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Could you tell me the app name or if your app name with space?

I have the same problem before on my app.
But this problem has been solved since I changed the app name with no space .

You can refer to my question here if you are in the same situation: 
[Sirikit StartAudioCall Fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39182936/sirikit-startaudiocall-fail/40083524#40083524)

Comment: I tried with different app names and it wasn't working, it was working just saying: "Send a message using myApp to John Smith" but not: "Send a message using myApp" than suddenly it worked again... very strange, I'm sorry I can't be more helpful. I'd like to understand why it was doing that.